# How is determined the context's dimension in Doc2Vec?

Tags: word2vec, word-embeddings, gensim

I would like to know how is determined the dimension of the context in `Gensim` `Doc2Vec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of the context in Gensim's Doc2Vec is determined by the parameter `vector_size` when you initialize the Doc2Vec model. This parameter sets the dimensionality of the output vectors.

For example, if you set `vector_size=100`, then the model will output 100-dimensional vectors for each document and word. This is a hyperparameter that you can tune based on your specific use case.

```py
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=100)
```

In this case, the dimension of the context (i.e., the output vectors) is 100. You can change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In [Genism's doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html),context is a list of words passed to models. That is a hyperparameter selected by the user, thus will problem specific.